# How can I view contents of a remote logfile in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, logging

I have a logfile in a remote location, and I want to view the contents of the logfile in local PowerShell. I want to perform this:

```
gc logfile.log | more
```

but, as mentioned, `logfile.log` is in a remote location.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you see the remote location? e.g. `gc \\UNC\path\to\logfile.log`

Comment: I have ip  address of the remote location where the logfile.log resides. @TechSpud

Comment: So, can you see the remote location? e.g. `gc \\IP\share\path\to\logfile.log`

Comment: gc \\IP\share\path\to\logfile.log in this IP is the ip address right? @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: @vm101 Yeah that's right

Comment: why do we use share here and path is nothing but the location of the file right? @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Please research remote file access on Windows. SO is not the right place to give you a crash course on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
gc \\<ip address or server name>\pathToFile\file.txt | more
```

For example, if the file named "File.txt", is in "c:\sharedFilesFolder" and the computer that holds this file has an IP address of "10.100.1.120" whereby the full path to the file is "\\10.100.1.120\sharedFilesFolder\File.txt" and you enabled sharing and gave read permissions for this folder then your command should look like this:

```
gc \\10.100.1.120\sharedFilesFolder\File.txt | more
```

Comment: it worked, But i want continuous streaming of the log file, any equivalent of tail -f  in windows @Amir

Comment: You'll have to post that as another question since it is a more detailed approach. This question should be marked as answered please.